# Kotlin :Can't get the price of the item of RecyclerView on Fragment

Tags: kotlin

I am attempting to make a recyclerView on Fragment ,
The idea is to get the price of the Item ,when the item been selected ,
and multiply by the select amount from the popup menu also.

Like below :

[image]

**The recyclerView model item : item_layout.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="#40E0D0"
    android:layout_height="200dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Price:"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="100"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

**The model of the item : Product.kt :**

```
    package com.gearsrun.popmenuapplication
    
    data class Product(var price : String)
private selectFuntion(itemPrice:Int){
    
}
```

**ProductAdapter.kt**

```
    package com.gearsrun.popmenuapplication

import android.graphics.Color
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_layout.view.*

class ProductAdapter(private val productList:List<Product>,private  val itemClick:(Int) -> Unit):RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder>() {


    private var selectedItemPosition :Int = 0
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false)
        return ProductViewHolder(itemView,itemClick)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = productList[position]
        holder.price.text =  currentItem.price.toString()
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            selectedItemPosition = position
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        if(selectedItemPosition == position){
            holder.itemView.cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FAFAD2"))
        }else{
            holder.itemView.cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = productList.size

    class ProductViewHolder(itemView: View, itemClick: (Int) -> Unit) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val price : TextView = itemView.price

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                itemClick(price.text.toString().toInt()) //sortOf if you need String, change that on String in every declaration
            }

        }



    }
}
```

**Fragment.kt**

```
       package com.gearsrun.popmenuapplication.fragment

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.PopupMenu
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.gearsrun.popmenuapplication.Product
import com.gearsrun.popmenuapplication.ProductAdapter
import com.gearsrun.popmenuapplication.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.*


class HomeFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_home) {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //init popup menu
        val popupMenu = PopupMenu(
            context,
            selectedTv
        )
        //add menu items to popup menu

        popupMenu.menu.add(Menu.NONE,0,0,"1")
        popupMenu.menu.add(Menu.NONE,1,1,"2")
        popupMenu.menu.add(Menu.NONE,2,2,"3")
        popupMenu.menu.add(Menu.NONE,3,3,"4")
        popupMenu.menu.add(Menu.NONE,4,4,"5")

        //handle menu clicks
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener {menuItem ->

            //get id of the item clicked
            val id = menuItem.itemId

            if(id==0){
                selectedTv.text = "1"

            }else if(id==1){
                selectedTv.text = "2"

            }else if(id==2){
                selectedTv.text = "3"

            }else if(id==3){
                selectedTv.text = "4"

            }else if(id==4){
                selectedTv.text = "5"

            }

            true



        }

        //handle button click,show menu
        selectedTv.setOnClickListener {
            popupMenu.show()
        }

        //display recyclerview

        val productList = generateProductList()
          fun selectFuntion(itemPrice: Int){
              Log.e("haha","You have click${itemPrice}")
          }
         var adapter = ProductAdapter(productList,::selectFuntion)
         giftRecycleView.adapter = adapter
        giftRecycleView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false)

    }

    private fun generateProductList():List<Product> {
        val list = ArrayList<Product>()
        list.add(Product(1))
        list.add(Product(2))
        list.add(Product(3))

        return list
    }


}
```

Can anyone help me modify my code ?
I will need that the item's value can be catch once click ,and multiply by the select amount ,in order to get the total price .

Thank you so much in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProductAdapter.kt
add this:

```
class ProductAdapter(
private val productList:List<Product>,
private val itemClick: (Int) -> Unit
): RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder>() {
```

delete this:

```
interface onItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(position: Int)
}
fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: onItemClickListener) {
    mlistener = listener
}
```

replace this:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductViewHolder {
       val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false)
        return ProductViewHolder(itemView,itemClick)
    }
```

replace this:

```
class ProductViewHolder(itemView: View, itemClick: (Int) -> Unit) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val price : TextView = itemView.price

    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            itemclick(price.text.toInt()) //sortOf if you need String, change that on String in every declaration
        }

    }

}
```

replace in fragment:

```
    var adapter = ProductAdapter(productList, ::yourFunction)
    giftRecycleView.adapter = adapter
```

add in fragment or ViewModel:

```
private yourFunction(itemPrice: Int) {
// do something with price
}
```

if you need to edit that price just make return type:
`(Int) -> Int` sort of :D 
and in adapter

```
price.text = itemclick(price.text.toInt()).toString()
```

Comment: Hello my friend ,Thank you soo much for you answer ,your answer is very clear and nice ,and I was testing them according to your suggestion .However ,I realize the part of init in the apdater document itemclick(price.text.toInt()) ,"toInt()"is not working .. and I don't understand very well about how to use it in the Fragment .Is it possible that you post the full code of the fragment and take a look if it happened the same to you of what I mentioned the error .. Mine is not working .Thank you so much for your patience !!

Comment: @YellowClock try this `itemclick(price.text.toString().toInt())`, i'm not done that all in IDE just in broser, so can make errors.  Forgot about that text is not a `String` but `CharSequence`

Comment: ,Thank you soooo much ,now the error remove ! Almost there !! The only last problem is the private yourFunction(itemPrice: Int)  ; I was trying to insert it into my ViewModel :Product.kt (I am not sure if I understood right ..) ,And It said lack of declaration .. I edit it in my code above ,could you please take a look,maybe it is easier for you to modify .Thank you so so much !!!

Comment: if you need that price in view model you need make that function not private and than something like this: `var adapter = ProductAdapter(productList, vm::yourFunction)` vm::yourFunction it's a link on that functiom in viewModel if it have been decleared in that fragment like `vm`. if you make that function right in fragment you can call it just `::yourFunction`

Comment: @YellowClock alsi you can just do something like this: `var adapter = ProductAdapter(productList) { price -> //do somthing with price }`;

Comment: ,Hi my friend ,Thank you soo much ,I was testing ,and been stuck at the part : var adapter = ProductAdapter(productList,selectFuntion(productList[]))  ; I had add the funtion : fun selectFuntion(itemPrice: Int){
              Log.e("haha","You have click${itemPrice}")
          }  ； I had already update the modify one on my code ,could you please let me know what I should put in the :var adapter = ProductAdapter(productList,selectFuntion(productList[])) ;or what I still lack of on my code ,it will help me a lot ..Thank you so much ,god bless you !

Comment: `var adapter = ProductAdapter(productList,selectFuntion(productList[]))` not like this, you need link a function, not call it. So that will be `::selectFuntion`

Comment: Thank you so much my friend ,thank you for your patince and I can tell you are very professional and smart . I was testing to see if I could get the value of the item .using  Log.e("haha","You have click${itemPrice}") in the selectFunction ,you can read it on my modified code above ,but still can't get anything ..I not sure what is going on .If it is possible ,please help me modify it when you are near your computer .However ,I can't thank you more angel !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236575/discussion-between-pentiux-and-yellow-clock).